# How do you configure the process startup timeout in IIS?

Tags: iis, timeout, startup

I'm running benchmarks on an IIS server to see how it scales.  I have an expensive start up process (reading in a lot of data from SQL, populating an AI network), but with 4 or more processors, it usually finishes in a few minutes.  I'm currently trying to start the web service with 2 processors and I keep getting this message:

`Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
Managed server didn't initialize after 120000 ms.`

After some searching, I find this is related to the IIS property: **startupTimeLimit**.  So I go into IIS, find the application pool and change the value:

[IIS AppPool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn9o4.png)

But this didn't change the outcome.  Also, I'm suspicious because the default value of the AppPool setting was 90 seconds and the documentation of **startupTimeLimit** says the default is 120 seconds, which corresponds to the error message.

How do I tell IIS not to shut down a long running initialization process?

Comment: ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core, but I didn't think it would make a difference as they both run on IIS.  That is, I thought this was an IIS configuration question.

Comment: You "didn't think", but the truth is documented by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attributes-of-the-aspnetcore-element ASP.NET Core has its own settings, which is outside of IIS. Show your web.config for others to review because it contains the key settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web.config file, locate the section `aspNetCore`, you can set the timeout limit here, using the following property: **startupTimeLimit**

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" startupTimeLimit="340" hostingModel="inprocess" >
```

The default=120, max=3600 and min=0

Taken from the documentation:

Optional integer attribute.

> Duration in seconds that the module waits for the executable to start
> a process listening on the port. If this time limit is exceeded, the
> module kills the process.
>
> When hosting in-process: The process is not restarted and does not use
> the rapidFailsPerMinute setting.
>
> When hosting out-of-process: The module attempts to relaunch the
> process when it receives a new request and continues to attempt to
> restart the process on subsequent incoming requests unless the app
> fails to start rapidFailsPerMinute number of times in the last rolling
> minute.
>
> A value of 0 (zero) is not considered an infinite timeout.